# Not able to see Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to build an application, it is running fine but it does not show the action bar. So I am not able to see my menu option. I am using API 23. 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIuCg.jpg) is the screenshot of the application.

here is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rishabh.agarwal.holmes.sunshine"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: do not show us build.gradle. Show Manifest, Activity onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Make your main `Activity` as child of `AppBarActivity` instead of `Activity` then you can see the action bar

Comment: How can you answer without any details in the question about the issue?

Comment: @gabriele it's because that's the common issue we freshers in android are facing:)

Answer (score 0):

Three things that should solve your problem are:

1. Check your theme styles if there you didn't set theme without action bar, but if you are using custom toolbar that is not substantially.(look at my third number)

   2. Check if your activity is extending `AppCompatActivity`
   3. And you could include in your layour custom toolbar and find view in java and then from there set programmatically toolbar like this: `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`